# gParted shows I/O error while creating a NTFS partition

Tags: partitioning, ntfs, gparted

Whenever I try to create a NTFS partition with gParted, I get this error (bolded for ease of sight):

```
GParted 0.18.0 --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize

Libparted 2.3

Create Primary Partition #1 (ntfs, 931.51 GiB) on /dev/sdc  00:10:46    ( ERROR )

create empty partition  00:00:01    ( SUCCESS )

path: /dev/sdc1
start: 2048
end: 1953523711
size: 1953521664 (931.51 GiB)
clear old file system signatures in /dev/sdc1  00:00:06    ( SUCCESS )

write 68.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 0  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 67108864  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 274877906944  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
write 4.00 KiB of zeros at byte offset 1000203087872  00:00:00    ( SUCCESS )
flush operating system cache of /dev/sdc  00:00:06    ( SUCCESS )
set partition type on /dev/sdc1  00:00:10    ( SUCCESS )

new partition type: ntfs
create new ntfs file system  00:10:29    ( ERROR )

mkntfs -Q -v -L "sitamsh" /dev/sdc1

Cluster size has been automatically set to 4096 bytes.
Creating NTFS volume structures.
Creating root directory (mft record 5)
Creating $MFT (mft record 0)
Creating $MFTMirr (mft record 1)
Creating $LogFile (mft record 2)
Creating $AttrDef (mft record 4)
Creating $Bitmap (mft record 6)
Error writing to /dev/sdc1: Input/output error
Error writing non-resident attribute value.
Couldn't create $Bitmap: Input/output error
========================================
```

How can I possibly solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try using the latest version of [GParted Live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) (currently 0.19.1-4).  The error appears to be in the mkntfs command which is part of the ntfs-3g package.